# I am trying to get the largest Sale in each Month and which week the sale is made from given DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas,  and I am trying to get Outcome Dataframe from df. Here I am trying to get the largest Sale in each Month and which week the sale is made.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Month": ["Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar"],"Week": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2],"Sales": [1000, 50, 200, 300, 250, 150, 100, 300]})

  Month  Week  Sales
0   Jan     1   1000
1   Jan     2     50
2   Jan     3    200
3   Jan     4    300
4   Feb     1    250
5   Feb     2    150
6   Feb     3    100
7   Mar     2    300
```

Output:

```
Outcome = pd.DataFrame({"Month": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],"Week": [1, 1, 2],"Sales": [1000, 250, 300]}) 

  Month  Week  Sales
0   Jan     1   1000
1   Feb     1    250
2   Mar     2    300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the indexes of the maximum sales values, then put that into [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to return the rows where the maximum sales of each month occur. I've added a [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get it in the same order/index as your example.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Month')['Sales'].idxmax()].sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  Month  Week  Sales
0   Jan     1   1000
4   Feb     1    250
7   Mar     2    300
```